# How to implement search functionality in SQL?

Tags: sql, search

How can I implement search functionality other than SQLQuery, Joins and conditional querys?

Comment: You should state what is your goal, then we can help with how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to use like condition:

```
select * from Table where fieldName like '%searchword%'
```

But it's very slow, so it's better to use full-text indexing: [in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), [in sql server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Full_Text_Search)

Answer (score 0):

Well, outside of SQL, you're left to the calling application to do searches. *Definitely* not the recommended choice if you can avoid it as you'll have to read all data first before searching it; indexing is a very powerful feature for databases.

If you want to display all data and *then* manipulate/sort/filter it, however, this method has its place.

Perhaps you wish to clarify your question as to what you're looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use something like [sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) or [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to implement a real search engine rather than using things that most databases provide, even mysql's full-text search.